# Как подтвердить платёж в Telegram.Bots?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Пытаюсь настроить в телеграм-боте оплаты. После отправки SendInvoiceAsync появляется форма для заполнения данных карты. Но после ее ввода ничего не происходит, то есть телеграм не оправляет мне апдейт с PrecheckooutQuery и по итогу оплата отваливается по таймауту. ИИспользую стандартную библиотеку C# Telegram.Bots .

Вот так создаю инвойс:

```
            await _telegramBotClient.SendInvoiceAsync(chatId: user.ChatId,
                                                  title: "Product",
                                                  description: description,
                                                  payload: "somePayload",
                                                  providerToken: _configuration["ProviderToken"],
                                                  currency: "RUB",
                                                  prices: price,
                                                  needEmail: true,
                                                  startParameter: "exapmle",
                                                  isFlexible:false
                                                  );
```

Вот так пытаюсь отловить подтверждение оплаты:

```
            if (update.Type==UpdateType.PreCheckoutQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Precheckout");
            await ExecuteCommand(CommandNames.CheckPay, update);
            return;
        }
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

**PreCheckoutQuery** отвечает за обработку и утверждение платежа перед тем, как пользователь его совершит.
Далее после утверждения, отправляем ответ серверу телеграма.
Ответ серверу телеграма вы должны дать в течении 10 секунд, иначе платеж не пройдет.
После того, как сервер телеграм получат ваш ответ, сервер тг в update вернет **SuccessfulPayment**.
**SuccessfulPayment** отвечает за обработку успешно проведенного платежа.

**Итого:**

```
PreCheckoutQuery preCheckout = update.PreCheckoutQuery;
if (preCheckout != null)
{
    await telegramBotClient.AnswerPreCheckoutQueryAsync(update.PreCheckoutQuery.Id, CancellationToken);
    SuccessfulPayment successfulPayment = update.Message.SuccessfulPayment;

    if (successfulPayment != null)
    {
        //Ваша логика
    }
}
```

В примере использован положительный ответ, но вы можете использовать ответ отрицательный используя следующую конструкцию:

```
await telegramBotClient.AnswerPreCheckoutQueryAsync(update.PreCheckoutQuery.Id, "ErrorMessage", CancellationToken);
```

Надеюсь помог, удачи в последующей разработке.

P.S На тесте без **SuccessfulPayment**.